# Visual Studio ASP.NET crashes after Stop Debug in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash

I'm working on a website which can stream audio files to the browser. It's a asp.net application which im developing in Visual Studio 2013. To stream the audio to the client im using partial content response using the range request headers. The code looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet, ActionName("GetFile")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string fileName)
    {
        var rootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "SoundFiles", fileName);

        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
        var mediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("audio/mpeg");

        var memStream = new MemoryStream(file);

        if (Request.Headers.Range != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var partialResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
                partialResponse.Content = new ByteRangeStreamContent(memStream, Request.Headers.Range, mediaType);
                return partialResponse;
            }
            catch (InvalidByteRangeException invalidByteRangeException)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(invalidByteRangeException);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var fullResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            fullResponse.Content = new StreamContent(memStream);
            fullResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
            return fullResponse;
        }
    }
```

Every time a song is played this method is called to get the file from the server and to stream it partially to the client. The whole application is built with signalr.

This worked perfectly for me there is nothing wrong with that code. Until i bought a new pc. I installed my Visual Studio 2013 normally on it including IIS Express 8.0 etc. But something strange happened to this.

If I start debugging with Google Chrome, and then if I do normal things to the website but not playing a song (not calling the method), and then stop debugging it again I have no problems. But if I start it in Chrome and play the song (call the method) and then try to stop debugging, visual studio freezes but there is no information that it is hanging. Its just hanging and I cannot close it. I cant even close it with the task manager. No error is showed. If I try to shut down my pc, then the pc won't shut down until I press the power button a long time. Now the strange thing: If I try the exact same thing but in Internet Explorer, Visual Studio works normally and is not hanging at all. This only happens if I use Chrome for debug and only on the same host as Visual studio is running. If I connect a Chrome on a other Device in my network, it does not have any effect.

I figured out, that I can run the application without debugging. If I do that it works good, but if I play a song and then try to close Visual Studio, it shortly hangs for about 30 seconds and then quits.

I am unable to find out what the problem is.

What I already tried to do:

- Reinstall Visual Studio 2013
- Try with Visual Studio 2015, same effect
- Reinstall Windows 8.1
- Reset Import/Export Settings in Visual Studio
- Run Visual Studio as Administrator
- Move SoundFiles to an other directory
- Try with Google Chrome Canary, same effect

And the really strange thing is, that it only happens on Chrome on the same machine, and only on my new pc. The same scenario works perfectly on my surface or on the old laptop.

What I could imagin, for the chrome reason is, that chrome uses range requests and ie does not. It takes the full Response of audio as 200 and chrome takes the range as partial content. This could be the problem, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to solve or workaround this problem.

Have you guys an idea, what could causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't manage to find the problem, but I found the solution. Because it was a new PC, there was little bit of bloatware on it. I've uninstalled the things I don't needed, and then it magically worked. No crashes anymore. I have a ASUS ROG G20AJ. I don't know exactly which of the bloatware was causing the problem, but it was some of them. So if you have a similar problem on a ASUS Machine, try uninstalling some of the not used software.

It wasn't Visual Studio crashing, it was the IIS Service. I really think that this is a really strange behaviour, because the crashes did only happen, if I executed the code snippet above... Anyways, it works now!